# What do I put for a ParameterType value in an ITK function call in Python?

Tags: python, vtk, itk

I'm trying to do this using the ITK Python bindings:

```
mi_metric = itk.MutualInformationImageToImageMetric[itk.Image.F3, itk.Image.F3].New()
mi_metric.SetFixedImage(i1)
mi_metric.SetMovingImage(i2)
v = mi_metric.GetValue( ? )
```

The `GetValue` function requires a `ParameterType` value to be passed to it, but I can't find any information about how to construct this type of object in the Python bindings.  Anyone know how I can get the mutual information value between these two images?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an [Array of double](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1CostFunction.html#adca09b241162b4dbbd99e7bb9b73292b), so I'd assume that you need to create an itk.Array of type double.

But this class is meant to be used with an optimizer, and not really meant to be used alone. So, I'd normally create an [Optimizer](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Optimizer.html), and use it with that.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is very well defined new application libary interface for ITK called SimpleITK.

You can learn more about that interface, and it's capabilities at www.simpleitk.org or by retrieving the software package from github.com/SimpleITK